Transactions failing for eth transfers in python using web3
I wanted to send USDT ERC-20 using this code and somehow I get errors for transfers some failed transaction hashes:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x93248ec63812699d7d4a96802755679306c49b3a0e0ea8ed1f923818a1aa4d38
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4322beb2b8ae95170060419ad529528155fc9a85cb7c579c7c28913acf1bd656
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2a61e69f399faf3a932a786e498368dae900c534a9dbb307b045dbd1a69b626e

from web3 import Web3

# Connect to Ethereum network (use Infura or your own node)
infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/api_key'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

# Check if connected to Ethereum network
if not web3.is_connected():
    print("Failed to connect to the Ethereum network.")
    exit()

# Replace these with your own information
private_key = ""  # Private key of the sender's wallet
fee_wallet_private_key = ""
fee_wallet_address = ""  # Wallet address paying the gas fees
sender_address = ""  # Your wallet address
recipient_address = ""  # Recipient's wallet address
usdt_contract_address = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"  # USDT token contract address on Ethereum mainnet
usdt_amount = 2300 * 10**6  # USDT has 6 decimal places

# USDT token contract ABI (simplified)
usdt_abi = [
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [{"name": "", "type": "address"}],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
    },
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [
            {"name": "_to", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "_value", "type": "uint256"},
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "bool"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function",
    }
]

# Initialize USDT contract
usdt_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=usdt_contract_address, abi=usdt_abi)

# Build the transaction to transfer USDT

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
fee_wallet_nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(fee_wallet_address)
gas_price = web3.eth.gas_price  # Get current gas price
gas_limit = 200000  # Estimate a gas limit for the transaction

# Create transaction
transaction = usdt_contract.functions.transfer(recipient_address, usdt_amount).build_transaction({
    'chainId': 1,  # Mainnet
    'gas': gas_limit,
    'gasPrice': gas_price,
    'nonce': fee_wallet_nonce,
})

# Sign the transaction
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, fee_wallet_private_key)

# Send the transaction
txn_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.raw_transaction)

# Print the transaction hash
print(f"Transaction sent: https://etherscan.io/tx/{web3.to_hex(txn_hash)}")

I don't understand where the issue is.
